# is there java version for the blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload?

Tags: java, jquery, angularjs, file-upload, blueimp

I have found this https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html  very interesting plugin to upload files with AngularJS which it has also a part with Google App engine. But i have not found JAVA implementation. Anyone knows if there is already a JAVA version ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link which is working with java: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Google-App-Engine-Java

All codes are given step by step. Hope it will help you.

For more, you can go through this tutorial also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824/2293534